# Starting PHPBrew FPM on system start

Tags: php

I am trying to build a vm, where exactly one user (as sudo or not) can brew and start a custom php build.

The current "default" php version should be started as phpbrew fpm process on system start. I was putting something like

```
phpbrew fpm start
```

in /etc/rc.local which seems to result in starting up the process. But the process is terminated as soon, as the rc.local script finished. It seems, that without an active login session, the process can't live.

Any suggestions, as how to make the fpm process survive?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: [this](https://gist.github.com/sprightly/2874ed24a595635cdc12) config might be good place to start.

Comment: Thanks. Worked nearly without customization. If you reply to my question, I could mark it as answer :-)

Comment: Done. Hope this is what you've meant :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify [this](https://gist.github.com/sprightly/2874ed24a595635cdc12) config according your needs.

Answer (score 0):

phpbrew 1.22.0 now supports "fpm setup --systemctl" command to help you setup the service.

be sure to enable --with-fpm-systemd when building your php.

Answer (score 0):

In phpbrew build directory it is exists ready file. For example:

```
~/.phpbrew/build/php-7.0.22/sapi/fpm/init.d.php-fpm
```

But more comfortable way is: temporary change owner of /etc/init.d to current user, then run command

```
phpbrew fpm setup --initd
```

then return back

```
sudo chown root:root /etc/init.d
sudo chown root:root /etc/init.d/phpbrew-fpm
```

and then

```
sudo update-rc.d phpbrew-fpm defaults
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run it in macOS.

```
sudo PHPBREW_PHP=$PHPBREW_PHP phpbrew fpm setup --launchctl
```

and then add it to your launchctl list.

```
# Activate a system-wide daemon to be loaded whenever the system boots up (even if no user logs in):
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/<path_to_phpbrew>.plist
```